# How do I make a button in javascript that gives a (random) different answer every time

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am new to javascript so this seemed a really helpful forum on the subject.
I only know basic HTML and CSS.

I want to make a button script, that when you click it, it gives you a different answer every time you click it. I know how to make a basic button that makes a text appear on the screen but I do not know how to script it to give a random different answer every time.

More specific:
I take like 20 different answers, each have an equal/unequal percentage of showing up on your screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the answers stored in a database or in the script?

Comment: And what about question(s)?

Comment: you need an array of posibles answers..

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you could generate a random number between 0 and 19

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*19);
   var randomAnswer = allAnswers[index];
   //display answer
});
```

And use it to index an array of 20 items

Comment: Smart, and 19 because that function also can "produce" result of 0 - 19 beying 0 the first position in the array. (+1)

Comment: Thank you TGH, but I am not sure how to execute it.

Comment: Update: Fixed a bug in the index calculation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start in Javascript:

```
var array=["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"];
var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
console.log(random);
```

So we set up an `array` of items, and pick a random item in that array and display it via `console.log`. What you need to do, is `bind` this to a `button` click, and append the `random` variable to a `div`, `span` etc.

Here's what you will need:

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfKnE/)

**HTML**:

```
<h1>Will be replaced</h1>
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var array=["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"];
    $('#button').bind('click', function() {

        var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        $("h1").html(random);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very fast and helpful comunity!

Answer (score 0):

This does it for 10: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/bx8sZ/

A small HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <button id="rnd">Random</button>
</div>
```

JS (using jQuery):

```
var answers = ["a1", "a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a8","a10"];
$("#rnd").click(function(){
    alert(answers[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))]);    
});
```